# Remove items from userform and spreadsheet at the same time

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Im trying to remove items in both userform and spreadsheet but when i click the remove button, the last item(paper transfer file(yellow)) is removed in userform but it's still in spreadsheet. Not sure what goes wrong.

items in userform

[image: 1]

items removed in userform

[image: 2]

last item remained in sheet

[image: 3]

please see below for the code.

```
    Dim s      As Long
    Dim ws     As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    Dim selectedItems As New Collection

   For s = s To Me.ListboxResult.ListCount - 1
            If Me.ListboxResult.Selected(s) Then
                selectedItems.Add s
            End If
        Next s

    For s = selectedItems.Count To 1 Step -1
        Me.ListboxResult.RemoveItem selectedItems(s)
        ws.Rows(selectedItems(s) + 4).Delete
        MsgBox "The selected item(s) Is/are successfully removed.", vbOKOnly, "Removal Successful"
    Next s
    
    'Uncheck the checkbox if the listbox is empty
    If Me.ListboxResult.ListCount = 0 Then
        Me.checkboxSelect.Value = False
        MsgBox "The selected item(s) Is/are successfully removed.", vbOKOnly, "Removal Successful"
    End If
```

I have this code below

```
    For Each Cell In rng
        With Cell
            With .Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With .Borders(xlEdgeRight)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
        End With
    Next Cell
```

I expect the item is removed in both userform and spreadsheet

Comment: What the row number of `paper transfer file(yellow)` on sheet?

Comment: Paper transfer file(Yellow) is on E7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete rows as you find them selected.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range, i As Long, c As Range
    Dim colItem As Long, sItem As String
    
    colItem = 1 ' 2nd column in listbox
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("E:E")
    With ListBoxResult
        For i = .ListCount To 1 Step -1
            If .Selected(i - 1) Then
            
                sItem = .List(i - 1, colItem)
                Set c = rng.Find(sItem, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                If Not c Is Nothing Then
                     c.EntireRow.Delete
                     Set c = Nothing
                Else
                     MsgBox sItem & " not found on sheet", vbExclamation
                End If
                .RemoveItem i - 1
            End If
        Next

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I think this code makes my program crashed every time. Idk why

Comment: @Learner11 Any error messages ?

Comment: No it’s just crashed after clicking the remove button

Comment: @leaner comment out the `c.EntireRow.Delete` and see if the listbox delete works. Ensure you have `Option Explicit` line.

Comment: I think I just figured something. See my edited code above. That maybe the reason it crashed. But I want to add a new row below every time it removes an item.

Comment: @Learner11 Did you add that border code to my answer ? If so, does my answer work without that addition ? IF `rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("E:E")` then you are formatting a million+ cells !

Comment: Yeah it works but I need to add rows below that code but not sure how.

Comment: @Learner11 Do you want to insert rows or just add borders to existing rows below the last entry in column E ?

Comment: I want to add borders to existing rows below column E and add checkbox as well. Also, how can I prevent checkbox from moving up the row when deleting items? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- `Me.ListBox1.Selected(s)` index is zero base. The index of `paper transfer file(yellow)` is `2`.
- `paper transfer file(yellow)` is in cell `E7` on worksheet
- You need to change code as below.

```
Debug.Print selectedItems(s) + 5 ' for testing to validate the row#
ws.Rows(selectedItems(s) + 5).Delete
```

---

Update:

> Question: because the items are not the same on the spreadsheet everytime I add to it

```vb
    Dim c As Range
    For s = SelectedItems.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set c = ws.Columns("E").Find(Me.ListBox1.List(SelectedItems(s)), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            c.EntireRow.Delete
            Set c = Nothing
            MsgBox "The selected item(s) Is/are successfully removed.", vbOKOnly, "Removal Successful"
        End If
        Me.ListboxResult.RemoveItem SelectedItems(s)
    Next s
```

Comment: What did you change? The only change is in `ws.Rows(selectedItems(s) + 5).Delete`. Change number from `4` to `5`.

Comment: Now I cannot remove the items in spreadsheet. I did change from 4 to 5.

Comment: I think I have the same problem even i changed from 4 to 5

Comment: Add `Debug.Print` as my revised code to double check the row#. The order of items in ListBox1 should be same as it is on sheet.

Comment: ok I put ```debug.print``` in my code and I tried adding items in removed them, the immediate windows displays 6,5,5

Comment: because the items are not the same on the spreadsheet everytime I add to it. It should be affected anyway

Comment: Then `ws.Rows(selectedItems(s) + 5).Delete` doesn't work. You have to locate the selected item on sheet and then delete rows.

Comment: How do I locate the selected item on sheet tho?

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: The error says 'Could not get the list property. Invalid property array index' in the line of ```Set c = ws.Columns("E").Find(Me.ListboxResult.List(selectedItems(s)), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)```. Also, the items cannot be removed in spreadsheet.

Comment: Wouldn't you delete the SelectedItem after deleting the sheet-row so the `.Find` would still have a value to search for?

Comment: What do you mean? Could you show me how please?

Comment: @Notus_Panda is right. `Find` should be executed before remove item from ListBox.

Comment: I tried putting the code before the code for listbox but it's still doing nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure how a multi-column exactly is as a value, wouldn't you have to specify which value (column) of the selected item you want?

Comment: I just need to delete the entire row and that includes the value in columns

Comment: because the items I want to delete is based on listbox, so I might just remove the entire row

Comment: @taller How should I place my code?

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand